# Spring MVC return json string exception

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc

I first use browser to request.
It can work.
But not with ajax code and thorw an exception.

```
2018-01-05 16:25:14 ERROR [com.ndl.gm.controller.BaseController] Could not parse accept header [application/json,&nbsp;text/javascript,&nbsp;*/*;&nbsp;q=0.01]: Invalid mime type "&nbsp;text/javascript": does not contain '/'
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not parse accept header [application/json,&nbsp;text/javascript,&nbsp;*/*;&nbsp;q=0.01]: Invalid mime type "&nbsp;text/javascript": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.resolveMediaTypes(HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.java:54)
    at
```

Here is my controller.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKuPb.png)

Comment: please Show the code of your controller

Comment: ajax headers.Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:JSESSIONID=57EC26AA354A7D05D09B8F033B57DFFA
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/gm/user/treeframe
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getMenu() { return new JSONArray();}

Comment: @Jens I just return a json array.

Comment: You have a Problem with your accept Header, so we Need to see How you have annotated the controller

Comment: @Jens Only Controller and RequestMapping

Comment: Please add it to your question

Comment: @Jens i have upload the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by trace the exception.
Then i find the ' text/javascript'.
It will be split to two mime.
But the string '&nbsp' don't contain '/'.
So it goes wrong.
The i would like to override the function in request getHeader, 
then i find i have been written the getHeader function to prevent xss attack. 
So, i just remove the code and it works.